# Как из метода вернуть список, или коллекцию?

Tags: dart

Язык Dart

```
void test() {
  int value1 = 2;
  int value2 = 5;
  return [value1, value2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Список](https://metanit.com/dart/tutorial/5.1.php):

```
List<int> test1() {
  int value1 = 2;
  int value2 = 5;
  return <int>[value1, value2];
}
```

[Коллекция](https://metanit.com/dart/tutorial/5.3.php), где каждый элемент имеет ключ и значение:

```
Map<String, int> test2() {
  int value1 = 2;
  int value2 = 5;
  return {'value1': value1, 'value2': value2};
}
```